# Saving Value of an UISlider to an Array doesn't work

Tags: iphone, ios, nsarray, uislider

im actual trying to save the usersettings inside a plist so that i can access them from everywhere. But when saving the UISlider value to my Array i always geht the message

> Sending 'float' to parameter of incompatible type 'id';

the Array looks like this:

```
NSArray *value = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: [theGradeSlider value], [theBackgroundSound isOn], [theButtonSound isOn], nil];
```

i also tried with MSMutableArray but this doesn't work too....

---

ANOTHER SOLUTION

i tried it know with NSUserDefaults and it worked.

to save the Settings (should be inserted in viewDidUnload or viewDidDiassappear):

```
NSUserDefaults *settings = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithUser:@"User"];

[settings setFloat:theGradeSlider.value forKey:@"theGradeSlider"];
[settings setBool:theBackgroundSound.on forKey:@"theBackgroundSound"];
[settings setBool:theButtonSound.on forKey:@"theButtonSound"];
[settings synchronize];
```

to load the Settings (should be inserted in viewDidLoad or ViewDidAppear):

```
NSUserDefaults *settings = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithUser:@"User"];

theGradeSlider.value = [settings floatForKey:@"theGradeSlider"];
theBackgroundSound.on = [settings boolForKey:@"theBackgroundSound"];
theButtonSound.on = [settings boolForKey:@"theButtonSound"];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that the values you are putting into the array are not objects.   In order to do this (although I would suggest a dictionary as opposed to an array), you would want to create `NSNumber` objects for each.

```
NSNumber *sliderValueObj = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: [theGradeSlader value]];
NSNumber *backgroundSoundObj = [NSNumber numberWithBool: [theBackgroundSound isOn]];
NSNumber *buttonSoundObj = [NSNumber numberWithBool: [theButtonSound isOn]];

NSArray *value = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: sliderValueObj,backgroundSoundObj,buttonSoundObj, nil];
```

or

```
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: sliderValueObj, @"slider",
                      backgroundSoundObj, @"backgroundSound",
                      buttonSoundObj, @"buttonSound",
                      nil];
```

For better form, use contents for the keys.

Comment: i just saw a tutorial where the parameter of a textfield and a datepicker where passed to an array in the way i did it, and everything worked fine. 
Seems to work know without any errors, thx

Comment: Of course, the parameters of textfields and date pickers are objects, but the `value` of a slider is a float.   This is why it won't work for your example above.

Answer (score 0):

This is true, you cannot store primitives in an array. You're probably better off saving them as `NSNumber` in the `NSUserDefaults`. That's what it's for.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the `NSNumber` class to store your values to the array. Methods in particular are `-numberWithFloat:` and `-numberWithBool`.

```
NSArray *value = [[NSArray alloc] 
         initWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:[theGradeSlider value]], 
                         [NSNumber numberWithBool:[theBackgroundSound isOn]], 
                         [NSNumber numberWithBool:[theButtonSound isOn]], nil];
```